# Compare array of objects and create a new array of object if they are different

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to compare two array of objects and create a new array of objects, if the array of objects are different. I have added an example below

Example:

const objA = [{"name":"Karthi","age":25,"education":"Masters","city":"Chennai","country":"India"}]

const objB = [{"name":"Meenakshi","age":28,"education":"UG","city":"Pune","country":"India"},{"name":"Mani","age":31,"education":"Masters","city":"Madurai","country":"India"}]

Expected Result: [{"oldName":"Karthi","newName":"Meenakshi","oldAge":25,"newAge":28,"oldEducation":"Masters","newEducation":"UG","oldCity":"Chennai","newCity":"Pune","country":"India"},{"oldName":null,"newName":"Mani","oldAge":null,"newAge":31,"oldEducation":null,"newEducation":"Masters","oldCity":null,"newCity":"Madurai","country":"India"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const capitalize = ([firstLetter, ...restOfWord]) =>
  firstLetter.toUpperCase() + restOfWord.join("");

const diff = objB.reduce((diff, currentObject, index) => {
  // Are there any differences at all between the current object being iterated over when comparing it objA vs objB?
  const isDiff = Object.entries(currentObject).some(
    ([key, value]) => (objA[index]?.[key] ?? null) !== value
  );

  // If there is not, then don't add any diff object.
  if (!isDiff) return diff;

  // If there is we need to push this new diff object onto the current accumulation.
  return [
    // The current diff objects up to this point in the iteration
    ...diff,
    // A new object that represents the diff with the old/new keys
    Object.entries(currentObject).reduce((prefixedObj, [key, value]) => {
      // If this particular key is the same in both objects, don't bother adding the new/old values and instead just add the key without a prefix
      if (value === objA[index]?.[key]) return { ...prefixedObj, [key]: value }

      // But if this key is different, add old/new keys and copy in the relevant values.
      const keyCapitalized = capitalize(key)
      return {
        ...prefixedObj,
        [`new${keyCapitalized}`]: value,
        // Use null for the old value if the key didn't exist in the objA array.
        [`old${keyCapitalized}`]: objA[index]?.[key] ?? null,
      };
    }, {}),
  ];
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks. Say I have a property country in the objects and in the result I want it without comparison because it will be same. Updated the code

Comment: @karthi Ive edited my code to achieve that, if you try again :)

Answer (score 1):

example of how you can achieve this using JavaScript:

```js
const objA = [{"name":"Karthi","age":25,"education":"Masters","city":"Chennai"}];
const objB = [{"name":"Meenakshi","age":28,"education":"UG","city":"Pune"},{"name":"Mani","age":31,"education":"Masters","city":"Madurai"}];

// compareAndCreateNewArray function takes two arrays of objects as input
const compareAndCreateNewArray = (objA, objB) => {
  // result array will store the final result
  let result = [];
  // loop through each object in objB
  objB.forEach(objBItem => {
    // flag to check if the current object in objB is found in objA
    let found = false;
    // loop through each object in objA
    objA.forEach(objAItem => {
      // if the name of the current object in objA matches the name of the current object in objB
      if (objAItem.name === objBItem.name) {
        // set the flag to true
        found = true;
        // temp object to store the properties with "old" and "new" prefix
        let temp = {};
        // loop through each key in the current object in objA
        Object.keys(objAItem).forEach(key => {
          // add "old" prefix to the key and store the value from objA in the temp object
          temp["old" + key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)] = objAItem[key];
          // add "new" prefix to the key and store the value from objB in the temp object
          temp["new" + key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)] = objBItem[key];
        });
        // push the temp object to the result array
        result.push(temp);
      }
    });
    // if the current object in objB is not found in objA
    if (!found) {
      // temp object to store the properties with "old" and "new" prefix
      let temp = {};
      // loop through each key in the current object in objB
      Object.keys(objBItem).forEach(key => {
        // add "old" prefix to the key and store null in the temp object
        temp["old" + key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)] = null;
        // add "new" prefix to the key and store the value from objB in the temp object
        temp["new" + key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)] = objBItem[key];
      });
      // push the temp object to the result array
      result.push(temp);
    }
  });
  // return the result array
  return result;
};

// log the result to the console
console.log(compareAndCreateNewArray(objA, objB));
```